# Apache fails to start in MAMP PRO version 4.0

Tags: apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I've just installed the latest version for MAMP PRO - Version 4.0.

I'm on a MacBook Air using OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6.

On starting the servers I receive a prompt instructing me that Apache has failed to start.

I then get a non-stop loading [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wn4e.png)

I've tried re installing MAMP PRO along with restarting my computer but the problem still persists.

Side note: It also asked me to upgrade MYSQL Databases which I did. I also performed a database repair inside MAMP PRO but again the problem is still there.

Not sure what else I should do. When starting up MAMP Pro the Apache loading icon seems to start straight away.

Answer (score 1):

What Mark did din't work for me either, but one of my hostnames was shown in red (probably not a valid path). After removing that host it was possible to start Apache.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you :) - I do have 1 duplicate hostname in red but this is because I have a login section on the site which uses https where the rest of the site only delivers through http.

So I need that duplicate hostname so MAMP can switch certificates when on the login page.

I also never had any problems with duplicate hostnames when using version 3 of MAMP Pro.

Comment: I'm currently running version 4.0.2 and am actually still having some issues with Apache starting when I enable Name resolution for "MAMP Viewer" on the General tab for a given host. I am unable to use this feature, but I can get Apache to start of I disable the feature, restart the servers, quit MAMP, then start MAMP again.

Comment: Hmm weirdly even that doesn't work for me! Apache just doesn't want to start. Glad I'm not the only one experiencing problems though. I'm having to use 3.5.2 until I can get it fixed which is annoying as I've bought a licence for 4.2.

Comment: Just updated to MAMP version 4.0.4 and everything seems to be working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to get it started again after going to the Apache tab, unchecking the Include Apache server in GroupStart checkbox, choosing restart the servers in the dialog, quitting MAMP, starting MAMP, then checking the Include Apache server in GroupStart checkbox again and choosing restart the servers in the dialog.

I’m not sure of the MAMP restart is necessary, but that is the order of things I did.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this didn't work for me. Still telling me that Apache has failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a problem with hosts as well. I've removed the last ones and the Apache started again. I don't understand the problem...

Comment: Yh I don't understand what's happening. We shouldn't have to remove duplicate hosts to get it to work it should just work! I need dup hosts due to a change in certificates.